# Undo git pull (forced update)

Tags: git

I've tried to revert last pushed commit to branch `dev`. After doing `git push -f` I realized that branch `master` was not at it's latest version on this machine, so I accidentally changed `master` as well.

My next step was to use different machine, where `master` was at latest version. The bad step was to run `git pull` on that machine, which updated all the branches, including `master`.

Is there any way to revert that last pull?

Comment: @HBHB I think I have different case, because the pull has force-updated commit tree, rather than fast-forwarded it

Comment: Have you looked at the `reflog`? In this case does that not `HEAD` you had before it was changed?

Comment: I think that `git checkout master; git reset --hard HEAD@{1}` can solve your problem.

Comment: The remedies in the linked-as-dup commit should work, though you have to do them on the machine that had the latest version of `master`.  The "forced update" is only to (that machine's) `origin/master`, so as long as its *local* master is good, you should be able to recover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no nice way of doing what you want, hence why a force push on git is highly advised against.

If you have the SHAs for the commits you've lost you can `cherry-pick` them, even though you can no longer see the commits in git any longer, it will still be able to reference them (I think!). Another option is to find another machine with the old commits on there, `cherry-pick` the commits you want, `revert` the commits you don't want and then do another `git push -f`. (And then try to never do a forced push again!)